# Editing the default Case Layout for Salesforce Communities

Tags: community, case

Can I edit the default Case Layout which comes in Cases tab of Communities without implementing it as a Custom VisualForce page. If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add the custom Case Layout to your Community User Profile.

Comment: Now that you've answered your own question, please mark the question as closed so it goes off the "unanswered" list.

Comment: haha I find this funny :D